# python while not done loop problems

Tags: python, while-loop

I have this Hangman game, it is all complete, but after I either win or loose it terminates the program. I am trying to incorporate a (while not done) statement in it, but can't seem to get it to work.Some help is greatly appreciated! Here is the code below, this is the first part:

```
import drawHangman
import turtle
import random

def main():

    #Do not change or remove code from herel
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.setup(400, 400, 200, 200)
    HG = turtle.Turtle()
    drawHangman.default(HG)


    print(" Welcome to the HangMan game!!")
    print(" You will have six guesses to get the answer correct.")
    print(" If you reach the limit of six wrong guess, it will be GAME OVER!")
    print(" Below you will see how many letter are in the word,\n","for eveyone you get right the line will be replaced with the letter.")

    lines = open("../WordsForGames.txt").read() 
    line = lines[0:] #lines 21-24 Randomly generate a word from a text file
    words = line.split() 
    myword = random.choice(words)
    #print(myword)# this print the random word
    done = False
    words = myword
    guessed = '_'*len(myword)
    guessedLetters = ""
    guesses = 0
    correctGuess = 0
    print(guessed)#this prints the blank lines.

    while(not done):    
        while correctGuess != len(myword):
            guess = input("Enter a letter you would like to guess: ")
            guessed = list(guessed)  #This will convert fake to a list, so that we can access and change it.
            if len(guess) == 1 and guess.isalpha():
                if guessedLetters.find(guess) != -1:
                    print("(",guess,")letter has already been picked")
                else:
                    guessedLetters = guessedLetters + guess
                    index1 = myword.find(guess)
                    if index1 == -1:
                        print("The letter(", guess,")is not a correct letter in the word", ''.join(guessed))
                        guesses = guesses + 1
                        print("You have guessed(", guesses,")times")
                        print("Remember that you only get 6 guesses!")
                        if guesses == 1:
                            drawHangman.drawHead(HG)
                        elif guesses == 2:
                            drawHangman.drawBody(HG)
                        elif guesses == 3:
                            drawHangman.drawRightArm(HG)
                        elif guesses == 4:
                            drawHangman.drawLeftArm(HG)
                        elif guesses == 5:
                            drawHangman.drawRightLeg(HG)           
                        elif guesses == 6:
                            drawHangman.drawLeftLeg(HG)
                            print("You reached your limit of 6 guesses, GAME OVER! The word was ("+ myword + ").")
                            break
                    else:
                        correctGuess = correctGuess + myword.count(guess)
                        print("The letter(",guess,")is in the word")
                        for ch in range(0, len(myword)):#For statement to loop over the answer (not really over the answer, but the numerical index of the answer)
                            if guess == myword[ch]:
                                guessed[ch] = guess #change the fake to represent that, EACH TIME IT OCCURS
                                print(''.join(guessed))
                                print("The letter(",guess ,")was in the word. Great job keep going")
                                if correctGuess != len(myword):
                                    print("You have guessed wrong(", guesses,")times!.")
                                    print("Remember that you only get 6 guesses!")
                                elif guesses <= 0:
                                    print("You reached your limit of 6 guesses, GAME OVER! The word was ("+ myword + ").")
                                    break
            else:"Guess any letter you want!"
        if correctGuess == len(myword):
            print("Congratulations! You won!")

    if (x == "n"):
        input("Would you like to play again?")
        done = True
    else:
        drawHangman.reset(HG)        
main()
```

this is the second part of the code which draws all the stuff like the head, body, arms, legs:

```
def default(babbage):
    #Start drawing stand
    babbage.penup()
    babbage.setpos(0,-50)
    babbage.pendown()
    babbage.back(100)
    babbage.fd(50)
    babbage.left(90)
    babbage.forward(175)
    babbage.right(90)
    babbage.forward(50)
    babbage.right(90)
    babbage.forward(25)
    babbage.right(90)
    #End drawing stand

def drawHead(babbage):
    babbage.pencolor("red")
    babbage.circle(15)
    babbage.penup()
    babbage.left(90)
    babbage.forward(30)
    babbage.pendown()

def drawBody(babbage):
    babbage.forward(65)
    babbage.back(40)
    babbage.right(90)

def drawRightArm(babbage):
    babbage.forward(30)
    babbage.right(180)
    babbage.forward(30)

def drawLeftArm(babbage):
    babbage.forward(30)
    babbage.back(30)


def drawRightLeg(babbage):
    #Move to lower body
    babbage.right(90)
    babbage.forward(40)
    #Draws the leg
    babbage.right(45)
    babbage.forward(40)
    babbage.right(180)
    babbage.forward(40)
    babbage.right(90)

def drawLeftLeg(babbage):
    babbage.forward(40)

def reset(babbage):
    babbage.reset()
    default(babbage)
```

Comment: Hmmm... where to start? First of all, where do you define `n`?

Comment: refer this, may help you - https://github.com/praba230890/guesswordgame/blob/master/game/main.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to give you a complete solution so you can work it out yourself, but the basic principle you're missing is that you need to *modify your while boolean inside the while loop itself*.

The structure you want is:

```
done = False
while (not done):
    *stuff*
    if [some condition meaning we should stop the loop]:
        done = True
```

This way, each time we go through the while loop, there is an opportunity for `done` to become `True`. As soon as it does, we can exit the loop.

The structure you have is:

```
done = False
while (not done):
    *stuff*
if [some condition meaning we should stop the loop]:
    done = True
```

That if statement is *outside the while loop*, meaning the only way we can get to `done = True` is if we have exited the loop. But, we can't get out of the loop unless `done` is already `True`, so how can we ever get to that reassignment line? The problem is that we don't have any opportunities to change the value of `done` inside the loop.

I would suggest looking at the lines inside the loop where you've put `break` - it looks like you want to exit out of the program around those points, so you may want to reassign `done` at that point also.

Answer (score 1):

Like alksdjg said, your changing of the `done` variable needs to be inside the while loop in order to for it to have any effect, and you need to think about why you have `break` statements if you would like the player to keep going.

Another thing, consider your lines 79 and 80; what is `x` and when are you checking what `input("Would you like to play again?")` is used for?

If you reconsider all these, the replaying functionality of your game should work properly.